# R - Calculate data sparsity - Mostly Categorical Data

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to calculate the sparsity value for my df. Through other posts and such I have been able to piece together a sort of working solution but the challenges is that there are 49 different values in the email column that represent there being no email. Is there a more efficient want to do this?

```
#caculate counts for individual terms
a <- sum(str_count(df1, "-"))
b <- sum(str_count(df1, "No Ethnicity"))
c <- sum(str_count(df1, "Unknown"))
d <- sum(str_count(df1, "No Marital Status"))
e <- sum(str_count(df1, "No Race"))
f <- sum(str_count(df1, "No Preferred Language"))

#sum the counts in order to create the numerator
z <- sum(a,b,c,d,e,f)

#calculate the sparsity value
z/(dim(df1)[1]*dim(df1)[2])
```

I have tried adding more than one term to each line but could not make it work. I have the list of email addresses in a notepad file, is there some way I could run a loop against it? I am not very advanced in R and am unfamilar with how a call like this would work. I have made similar things work with batch files.

Something like:

for each value in %filename%
occur <- sum(str_count(df1, "value from file"))
total <- sum(occur, total)
next
total

Or if that won't work is there a way to enter multiple terms in the same command?

Of course if you have a suggestion to accomplish the same task in a totally different way I am happy to hear that as well. Just trying to calculate data sparsity for categorical data.

Thank you

Comment: `sum(str_count(df1, "-|No Race|Unknown|No Marital Status| ...."))` should work

Comment: @Jon Spring Yes! that totally worked. I was doing the equivalent of sum(str_count(df1, "-", "No Race", "Unknown", "No Marital Status")) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Jon Spring posted this solution in the comments:

```
sum(str_count(df1, "-|No Race|Unknown|No Marital Status| ...."))
```